# Homomorphism between elliptic curves $C: y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$ and $\bar{C}: y^2=x^3-2ax^2+(a^2-4b)x$.

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-homomorphism

I am reading Rational Points on Elliptic Curves by Silverman and Tate. In Section 3.4, Page 76, the authors defined two elliptic curves  elliptic curves $C: y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$ and $\bar{C}: y^2=x^3-2ax^2+(a^2-4b)x$ and a map $\phi: C\rightarrow \bar{C}$ by
$$\phi(x,y)=\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}, y(\frac{x^2-b}{x^2})\right).$$

On page 80, they try to show that if $P_1, P_2, P_2 \in C({\mathbb{Q}})$ are colinear, then the image of the three points $\phi(P_1), \phi(P_2), \phi(P_3)\in \bar{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ are also colinear.

Suppose the line passing through $P_1,P_2,P_3$ is $y=\lambda x+\nu$. They claim that the line intersecting $\bar{C}$ is
$$y=\bar{\lambda}x+\bar{\nu}, \text{ where } \bar{\lambda}=\frac{\nu\lambda-b}{\nu} \text{ and } \bar{\nu}=\frac{\nu^2-a\nu\lambda+b\lambda^2}{\nu}.$$

I don't know how they come up with these formula. The exact words in the book are "The line intersecting $\bar{C}$ that we take is". It seems pretty obvious to take. But I couldn't derive them using the known fact.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, then you are asking how to come up with the formula for the line $\bar{C}$.

Well, one down-to-earth method to gain some intuition would be to look at explicit instances of curves $C$ together with three colinear points $P_1, P_2, P_3$ and then apply $\phi$ to the points. Then one can calculate $\bar{C}$ explicitly, and will see that $\lambda$ relates to $\bar{\lambda}$ and $\nu$ to $\bar{\nu}$ exactly as in their formula. Looking at enough instances one can then infer the general formula.

EDIT (more general explanation):

Let us say that the points $P_i$ has coordinates $(x_i, y_i)$. Because they are colinear we have that $\lambda = \frac{y_j-y_i}{x_j-x_i}$ for $i \not = j$. Now, we can apply $\phi$ and obtain formulas for $\phi(P_i)$ in terms of $x_i$ and $y_i$. Now we can compute the slope $\bar{\lambda}$ for the line between the points $\phi(P_i)$ using the same formula with the new coordinates.

I have not done the computations, but I am confident that it will match with the formulas in the book. Accordingly with $\bar{\nu}$.

Comment: Thanks! So you meant the formulas are obtained by trial and error? I agree it is possible.

Comment: Trial and error is certainly one way, but I am not saying it is the only way and that it was obtained this way. I only meant to give an idea for obtaining some intuition. The group law for elliptic curves was known long before computers came long, and so trial and error back then must have been very tedious. So most likely one can derive it by more advanced means.

Comment: Upon further thinking there is a general, yet tedious way to derive the formula for $\bar{C}$. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Unfortunately I did that already but couldn't get anywhere. But possibly because I stopped after using 2 pages of paper thinking there should be an easier way. I'll try it again.